# how to get the optimal number of cluster from dissimilarity (diana, cluster R package) output?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to get the optimal number of clusters from a dendrogram obtained with the cluster package and diana method (used euclidean dissimilarity) with the following:

```
mydatad <- diana(mydata, stand = FALSE)
mydata_dend <- fviz_dend(mydatad, cex = 0.5, k = 2, palette = "jco") 
## use factoextra and ggplot2 for visualization
```

then I try to use the dissimilarity matrix with NbClust:

```
NC <- NbClust(data = NULL, diss = mydatadd, distance = NULL, min.nc = 2, max.nc = 50, method= "single", index = "silhouette")
```

and I get this error message":

```
Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

however my data has no missing values, the lowest values in the dissim matrix should be 0 for identical elements (mydata is ~2000 elements , 11 variables).

Then I tried to estimate the dissim . distance using the original data and estimating the euclidean distance, thus not using the dissimilarity matrix

```
NC <- NbClust(T2141d, diss = NULL, distance = "euclidean", min.nc = 2, max.nc = 50, method= "single", index = "silhouette")
```

and I get the following error message:

```
Error in t(jeu) %*% jeu : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

any suggestions are welcome, even suggestion for different methods to obtain the optimal number of cluster. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

The `NbClust` function requires a dissimilarity matrix. When you run `diana`, the object returned is not a dissimilarity matrix, although it was calculated. You need to set `keep.diss=TRUE`. Before I show how to return the dissimilarity matrix using an example dataset:

```
library(factoextra)
library(cluster)
mydata=data.frame(matrix(runif(2000*11),ncol=11))
mydatad <- diana(mydata, stand = FALSE,keep.diss=TRUE)
# check the dissimilarity matrix stored
class(mydatad$diss)
[1] "dissimilarity" "dist"

NC <- NbClust(data = NULL, diss = mydatad$diss, 
distance = NULL, min.nc = 2, max.nc = 50, 
method= "single", index = "silhouette")
```